# MySQL: Get count of consecutive records (date)?

Tags: mysql, database

Need to get amount of days a user has completed a habit in a row (streak). This means the latest streak (today backwards) and not necessarily their longest streak.

With the following dates inserted, I'm expecting 4

- 2023-09-14
- 2023-09-15
- 2023-09-16
- 2023-09-17

This query is returning 1 consistently, where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT s.habit, MAX(s.streak) AS currentStreak
  FROM ( SELECT IF(@prev = o.habit_id AND o.date = @prevDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                  , @streak := @streak + 1
                  , @streak := 1
                ) AS streak
              , @prev := o.habit_id AS habit
           FROM ( SELECT t.habit_id
                       , DATE(t.created_at) AS `date`
                    FROM habit_progress_logs t
                   CROSS
                    JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @prevDate := NULL, @streak := 1) i
                   GROUP BY t.habit_id, DATE(t.created_at)
                   ORDER BY t.habit_id, DATE(t.created_at)
                ) o
       ) s
  WHERE s.habit = 4
 GROUP BY s.habit
```

[SQLFiddle with schema and data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwmV8CKA3cuuMCapseoV2H/4)

Comment: *where am I going wrong?* You think that user-defined variables processing order matches your logic which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to set `@prevDate` for each row, and you are returning max streak instead of most recent streak.

If you are using MySQL >= 8.0 you can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), instead of the [deprecated setting of user variables in expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-deprecation-removal):

```sql
WITH streaks AS (
    SELECT
        habit_id,
        DATE(created_at) AS dt,
        DATE(created_at) - INTERVAL DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY DATE(created_at) ASC) DAY AS grp
    FROM habit_progress_logs
    WHERE habit_id = 4
),
streaks2 AS (
    SELECT
        habit_id,
        grp,
        COUNT(DISTINCT dt) AS length,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY habit_id ORDER BY grp DESC) AS rn
    FROM streaks
    GROUP BY habit_id, grp
)
SELECT habit_id, length AS currentStreak
FROM streaks2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The first [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) gives us the date sequence grouping, using [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) (`rnk` added for illustration):

| habit_id | dt | rnk | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-07-14 | 1 | 2023-07-13 |
| 4 | 2023-07-15 | 2 | 2023-07-13 |
| 4 | 2023-07-16 | 3 | 2023-07-13 |
| 4 | 2023-07-17 | 4 | 2023-07-13 |
| 4 | 2023-07-19 | 5 | 2023-07-14 |
| 4 | 2023-08-20 | 6 | 2023-08-14 |
| 4 | 2023-08-21 | 7 | 2023-08-14 |
| 4 | 2023-08-23 | 8 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-08-24 | 9 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-08-25 | 10 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-08-26 | 11 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-08-27 | 12 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-08-28 | 13 | 2023-08-15 |
| 4 | 2023-09-13 | 14 | 2023-08-30 |
| 4 | 2023-09-14 | 15 | 2023-08-30 |
| 4 | 2023-09-15 | 16 | 2023-08-30 |
| 4 | 2023-09-15 | 16 | 2023-08-30 |
| 4 | 2023-09-16 | 17 | 2023-08-30 |
| 4 | 2023-09-17 | 18 | 2023-08-30 |

The second [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) does the GROUP BY and adds the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

| habit_id | grp | length | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-08-30 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-08-15 | 6 | 2 |
| 4 | 2023-08-14 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2023-07-14 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 2023-07-13 | 4 | 5 |

If you are stuck on MySQL < 8.0:

```sql
SELECT habit_id, COUNT(*) AS currentStreak
FROM (
  SELECT
    habit_id,
    dt,
    @grp := IF(@prevHabitId = habit_id AND dt = @prevDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY, @grp, @grp + 1) AS grp,
    @prevDate := dt,
    @prevHabitId := habit_id
  FROM (
    SELECT habit_id, DATE(created_at) AS dt
    FROM habit_progress_logs
    JOIN (SELECT @prevHabitId := NULL, @prevDate := NULL, @grp := 0) i
    WHERE habit_id = 4
    GROUP BY habit_id, dt
    ORDER BY habit_id, dt
  ) s
) t1
GROUP BY habit_id, grp
ORDER BY habit_id, grp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XW-Peuv1)

Comment: Many thanks, I've accepted the answer :)